# Run a shell command or executable file from a VSIX installer package?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm working manually the vsixmanifest of a VSIX extension package, is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vsix Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
  <Identifier Id="c669b00e-3746-47bd-bfe7-e6f9d64458ff">
    <Name>RapidDesign</Name>
    <Author>ZUI INFRA sp z o. o.</Author>
    <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    <Description>RapidDesign allows you to use various VisualStudio designers faster.</Description>
    <Locale>1033</Locale>
    <MoreInfoUrl>http://www.rapiddesignaddin.com</MoreInfoUrl>
    <License>EULA.txt</License>
    <Icon>Speedometer.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>RapidDesignPreview.png</PreviewImage>
    <InstalledByMsi>false</InstalledByMsi>
    <SupportedProducts>
      <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
        <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
    </SupportedProducts>
    <SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.0" MaxVersion="4.0" />
  </Identifier>
  <References>
    <Reference Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF" MinVersion="10.0">
      <Name>Visual Studio MPF</Name>
    </Reference>
  </References>
  <Content>
    <VsPackage>RapidDesign.pkgdef</VsPackage>
  </Content>
</Vsix>
```

There is a way to tell the VSIX installer to run automatically a CMD command or an executable file, like a kind of post-installation step?

For example I would like to run/install a registry script (.reg file) that configures some default extension options for me, but I don't know if that process can be done automated from the vsixmanifest launching a console command or an EXE process previously programmed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vsix package shouldn't rely on the registry for its settings, [there is a specific API to access the Visual Studio settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460144.aspx) systems. A [normal vsix package cannot call or start anything after deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee943167%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). You can let the package itself setup defaults the first time it is started.

If you really need more advanced things during your setup, you can create a `.msi` instead of a vsix. [You'll need to extract your vsix and include its contents in your Windows Installer package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee332502.aspx). Or you can use WixToolset to create a MSI installer and use the [`<VsixInstaller>` element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/vs/vsixpackage.html) to register the Visual Studio Package, you can put the other logic in the Wix installer project.

Comment: Thanks, I've choosed other alternative more easy, an SFX installer that runs the vsix package and the regfile. Really learning MSI just to run a file seems not a good idea for me, thanks again!